# Getting Randomly Error:Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists:

Tags: spring, hibernate

In my program code and entity are working fine, but randomly at any point of time this error comes.
If i restart the server's it starts working but after some days again same issue is coming.
Below are the log scripts of the error:

```
com.pb.gpp.backoffice.job.Exception.GPPBackOfficeException: Error occured during select operation in following method and tablegetFileTypeDetail, transactionfiletype and transactionfiledetail
        at com.pb.gcs.backoffice.transaction.controller.DaoImpl.getFileTypeDetail(DaoImpl.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.getFileTypeDetail(Unknown Source)
        at com.pb.gcs.backoffice.transaction.filecreate.writer.TransactionFileWriter.getCompletePath(TransactionFileWriter.java:178)
        at com.pb.gcs.backoffice.transaction.filecreate.writer.TransactionFileWriter.initializeItemWriter(TransactionFileWriter.java:163)
        at com.pb.gcs.backoffice.transaction.filecreate.writer.TransactionFileWriter.beforeStep(TransactionFileWriter.java:61)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.pb.gcs.backoffice.transaction.model.configuration.TransactionfiledetailEntity#311]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:244)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1098)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:671)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:489)
        at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:667)
        at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:190)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2926)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1673)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1605)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1505)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:713)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:943)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(
```

```
 public FileTypeDetail getFileTypeDetail(String partnerId, String carrier) throws GPPBackOfficeException {
    try {
        Session session = configurationSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.clear();
        String query = " Select tft.*, tfd.*" +
                "from transactionfiletype tft " +
                "join transactionfiledetail tfd " +
                "on tft.filetype=tfd.filetype " +
                "where tfd.activeflag=1 and tfd.filetype ='transactionfile' and tfd.partnerid =:partnerId and tfd.carrier =:carrier";

        Query queryFileTypeMapping = session.createSQLQuery(query)
                .addEntity("transactionfiletype", TransactionfiletypeEntity.class)
                .addEntity("transactionfiledetail", TransactionfiledetailEntity.class);

        queryFileTypeMapping.setParameter("partnerId", partnerId);
        queryFileTypeMapping.setParameter("carrier", carrier);

        List<Object[]> resultList = queryFileTypeMapping.list();
        session.flush();
        List<FileTypeDetail> fileTypeDetailList = new ArrayList<FileTypeDetail>();
        FileTypeDetail fileTypeDetail;

        for (Object[] fileDetail : resultList) {
            fileTypeDetail = new FileTypeDetail();
            fileTypeDetail.setTransactionfiletypeEntity((TransactionfiletypeEntity) fileDetail[0]);

            fileTypeDetail.setTransactionfiledetailEntity((TransactionfiledetailEntity) fileDetail[1]);
            fileTypeDetailList.add(fileTypeDetail);
        }
        return fileTypeDetailList.get(0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        GPPBackOfficeException gppBackOfficeException = new GPPBackOfficeException(Constants.SYSTEM_PREFIX, Constants.ERROR_CODE_0019, helper.getExceptionInfo(Constants.SYSTEM_PREFIX, Constants.ERROR_CODE_0019).getErrorclientmessage()
                + "getFileTypeDetail, transactionfiletype and transactionfiledetail", ex);
        throw gppBackOfficeException;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to say what your code is doing wrong without seeing it. It seems there is an id cached of your TransactionfiledetailEntity, which is actually deleted in the data base, when you try to read it.

Comment: @UweAllner I have attached the code,In this select call its getting no row found  but data exist in db,
Also veried in same query in DB

Comment: Why you do `session.clear()`? Is `configurationSessionFactory`manged by Spring? Why you don't/Do you have `@Transactional` annotation (at least with `readOnly=true`) ?

Comment: @xerx593 yes i have used in Transactional annotation.